# Mysql: not getting maximum row id

Tags: mysql

Sample data:

```
 id            user_id st_type st_val    created_at
4936425     427067  2   1   2014-01-29T12:38:46.000Z    
5066178     427067  2   1   2014-02-04T14:57:29.000Z    
5704102     427067  2   1   2014-03-11T09:01:31.000Z
```

user3_status contains multiple rows with different status.
     I am trying to get 28 feb row but below query getting 4th row.
        Need suggestions??

for example for user_id=11233

```
contains 2,1(status_type,status_value) 4 rows.
1st row on=12 feb
2nd row on=18 feb
3rd row on=28 feb
4th row on=3 march

select u3.id
from user u3,user3_status us
where 
u3.id=us.user_id
and us.id IN(select max(id) from user3_status where user_id=u3.id and status_type IN(2) )
and us.status_value=1 
and year(us.created_at)=2014
and month(us.created_at)=02
```

Comment: sample data maybe or fiddle ?

Comment: Share actual data from the table.

Comment: Perhaps a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) could illustrate the issue better?

Comment: added sample data,getting 5704102 id..looking for 5066178    id

Comment: That SQL (when I hacked it to work) brings back nothing. The sub query is getting the latest rowfor st_type of 2 for the user id. This will be 5704102. But as the resulting record is for month 03 and you only want month 02 in the WHERE clause the resulting row is dropped.

Comment: could you suggest some query change such that i get feb highest row..

Answer (score 0):

Best guess as to what you want (as the column names in the query do not match the table details, and you have only given one of the 2 tables details) would be something like this:-

```
SELECT us.*
FROM user u3
INNER JOIN user3_status us ON u3.id = us.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, YEAR(us.created_at) AS year_created, MONTH(us.created_at) AS month_created, max(id) AS MaxId
    FROM user3_status 
    WHERE st_type IN(2) 
    GROUP BY user_id, year_created, month_created
) Sub1
ON us.user_id = Sub1.user_id
AND YEAR(us.created_at) = Sub1.year_created
AND MONTH(us.created_at) = Sub1.month_created
AND us.id = Sub1.MaxId
WHERE WHERE us.st_val=1 
AND YEAR(us.created_at) = 2014
AND MONTH(us.created_at) = 2
```